# What is SafariDAVClient doing hogging up memory?

Tags: macos, safari, icloud

I felt that my computer was slow today so I checked Activity Monitor. What I found was a process called SafariDAVClient hogging up 3.32GB of memory.

I am not even running Safari. Has anyone seen this problem? I've recently updated to 10.7.2 and my first suspicion is iCloud syncing. If anyone else is having the same problem, we should probably file a bug to Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same problem after updating to 10.7.2. SafariDAVClient also caused CPU-spikes all the time.

Disabling Bookmark Sync in the iCloud preferences, coupled with a reboot "solved" it.

It wouldn't hurt if you would file a bugreport with Apple as well. My ID is rdar://10280447, it's still open.

Answer (score 0):

I also get this problem from behind an NTLM authenticated proxy at work.
If I switch to a network without the NTLM proxy the process quits and I'm back to normal.
I also had this problem with other processes like syncdefaultsd when behind the proxy.

While I'm going through the proxy I turn off iCloud.

Lots of things don't work behind the proxy, like AppStore.
I'm looking at using cntlm or ntlmaps (local proxy relay), and then using the Network settings in System Preferences to point to the local proxy, to see if that may solve it. Although our firewall blocks almost anything but port 80 and 443, so that could be an added problem.

I've used cntlm on Windows before and it is good, but I'll need to compile it for OS X, but not yet, not yet (later).

Answer (score 0):

I had to throw the folder SafariDAVclient in the trash. I tried to take Safari off the icloud and stop the bookmark sync, but that did not help. Everything is fine now.